# "coffee" command fails silently, how to debug?

Tags: coffeescript

When using coffee-script this command runs ok on 1 computer but silently fails on another.

```
coffee --output dir --compile dir
make: *** [js] Error 1
```

How can I debug? Any flags for verbose output?

```
npm list -g
/usr/local/lib
├─┬ coffee-script@1.7.1
│ └── mkdirp@0.3.5
├── csso@1.2.15
└── uglify-js@1.3.2
```

Even `coffee --version` fails with no output

Comment: what version are you using? Is it the same on both machines?

Comment: @jcollum, 1.7.1 on both

Comment: Hmm, I was hoping it would be easy. What's with the ***, is that the actual output or is that something else? What OS are you on?

Comment: Ubuntu on both, I gave this string to show error code `1`, for simple `coffee ...` command - no output at all

Comment: What's the output of `which coffee`?

Comment: @EvanHahn, yes, that's different: `/usr/bin/coffee` and `/usr/local/bin/coffee`

Comment: I think that's all caused by old versions (in repos) of `node`, `npm` and all this stuff.

Comment: Is /usr/local/bin/coffee and /usr/... pointing to a symlink? It looks like coffee isn't installed correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a terrible mix of old Ubuntu's/new packages.

1. Needed to remove `node, nodejs` packages.
2. Install new versions [from PPA](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager#ubuntu-mint-elementary-os)

   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install python-software-properties python g++ make nodejs
3. Reinstall `coffee-script`: `sudo npm install coffee-script -g`

Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very confusing, I never would have figured it out without your specific instructions.